# Solving ODE y'(x)=2 x y(x), using power expansion

Tags: calculus

I have this equation:

$$y'(x)=2 x y(x)$$,

I want to solve this ODE with differential equation with power expansion. 
I get a problem cause I do not get how to equate the coefficients.

$$2 x y(x)=2 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_0 x+2 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_1 x^2+2 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_2 x^3+2 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_3 x^4+2 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_4 x^5+2 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_5 x^6+2 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_6 x^7+\text{...}+2 a_n x^{n+1}$$

$$y'(x)=\text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_1+2 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_2 x+3 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_3 x^2+4 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_4 x^3+5 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_5 x^4+6 \text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_6 x^5+\text{...}+(n+2) a_{n+2} x^{n+1}$$

When equation these coefficients how do I deal with $\text{$\unicode{0008}$a}_1$, which does not have a x term, when I set that to zero I can go back and find that all the coefficients are zero and the entire expression dissapears, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure every term dissapears? What about those with even index?

Comment: Also, recalling that $e^{x^2} \approx 1+x^2+x^4/2+\ldots$ may be useful here...

Comment: Thanks:)I know that, I have no problem solving it given that the coefficients does not cancel. But I guess I need to have a closer look at why not the even vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_1$ is 0,
since there is no constant term
in the other side..

From $x$: $2a_0 = 2a_2$ or $a_2 = a_0 $.

From $x^2$: $2a_1 = 3a_3$ or $a_3 = 2a_1/3 = 0$.

From $x^3$: $2a_2 = 4a_4$ or $a_4 = a_2/2 = a_0/2$.

and so on,
with the odd exponent terms
being zero..

All the coefficients
are in terms of
$a_0$.

Another way to looks at this is
$y'(x)/y(x) = 2x$
or
$(\ln(y))' = 2x$
or
$\ln y = x^2+c$
or
$y(x)
=e^{x^2+c}
$
which has only even terms.

Comment: Where can I find a proof that I can set a1 to any variable?

Comment: $a_0$ is what you may set to any value because, at the end of the day, you will be able to express your solution as $y = a_0 + a_2 x^2 + a_4 x^4 = a_0 (1+P(x))$, where $P$ is some polynomial. Since your equation is homogenous and we are not provided with either initial or boundary conditions, any choice of $a_0$ yields to a solution.

Comment: I fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: Odd exponents or coefficients- see ur answer

Answer (score 1):

$a_1$ is 0, but $a_0$ is not, so there are only even terms (all odd terms vanish because $a_1 = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

So if we write out the summation as such,

$$
y(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k x^k \\
y'(k) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n k a_k x^{k-1} \\
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k a_k x^{k-1} = y'(k) = 2xy(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2 a_k x^{k+1} \\
$$

By shifting the indexes around,

$$
\sum\limits_{k=-1}^{n-1} (k+1) a_{k+1} x^{k} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} 2 a_{k-1} x^{k} \\
$$

We get the relation $ (k+1) a_{k+1} = 2 a_{k-1} $, or $ \frac{k+2}{2} a_{k+2} = a_k $.

By looking at previous equations, we see that only one side has constant terms, so $ a_1 $ is zero. Thus all odd terms are zero.

We can expand the even coefficients into different series depending on the initial conditions of the differential equations. Notice that the series is infinite for non-zero $ a_0 $.